# Какие исключения могут возникнуть в приведённом ниже коде на языке Python?

Tags: python, файлы, исключения, логирование

Какие исключения могут возникнуть в приведённом ниже коде на языке Python?

```
f = open('/logs/daemon.log', 'a+')
print(f.write('Hello World!'))
```

Могут ли это быть исключений из списка ниже?

1. IndexError
2. IOError
3. OSError
4. TypeError
5. ValueError

Comment: Это учебное задание? По правилам вы должны хотя бы попытаться решить его самостоятельно.

Comment: @CrazyElf, это не учебное задание.

Answer (score 3):

Функция [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), судя по описанию, может выбросить следующие исключения:

- OSError
- ValueError
- IOError
- FileExistsError
- InterruptedError

---

**PS.**

Если вам это нужно, чтобы ловить возможные ошибки, то лучше использовать общие типы, например `Exception`

Пример:

```
import traceback

try:
    with open('NOT_FOUND') as f:
        pass

except Exception:
    print("ERROR:\n" + traceback.format_exc())
```

Результат:

```
ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<...>.py", line 10, in <module>
    with open('NOT_FOUND') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'NOT_FOUND'
```

Если нужно ловить конкретные, то:

```
import traceback

try:
    with open('NOT_FOUND') as f:
        pass

except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(f"FileNotFoundError: {e}")

except Exception:
    print("ERROR:\n" + traceback.format_exc())
```

Результат:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'NOT_FOUND'
```

Comment: А вот например при каком условии может выйти `ValueError`? Судя из того же описания, это может произойти только при проблеме невозможности закодировать строку в нужную кодировку. В данном куске кода проблем с кодировкой вроде бы не должно быть. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @CrazyElf, кусок кода для примера обработки исключений, но и он выдаст ту ошибку: `'strict' to raise a ValueError exception if there is an encoding error. The default value of None has the same effect.`, т.к. значение по-умолчанию аналогично явно заданному `'strict'` :)

Comment: "raise a ValueError exception if there is an encoding error" ну вот я говорю про то, что тут не от куда вроде "encoding error" взяться. Мне просто интересно - тут же нужно по конкретному коду анализ провести, а не в теории что может произойти? )

Comment: OSError дважды упомянули.

Comment: Можете пояснить, что значит первый слэш в пути к файлу daemon.txt? Он лежит в папке logs, а сама папка и исполняемый .py файл лежат в одном каталоге. При выполнении .py файла в консоли возвращается ошибка:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/logs/daemon.log'

Comment: И ещё, я так понял ValueError может возникнуть только при указании encoding параметра в open? А если не указать, то этой ошибки быть не может?

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы ответить на этот вопрос вы должны для каждого исключения из данного вам списка:

- прочитать описание исключения
- прочитать описание используемых в коде функций и операторов
- подумать, создаются ли в этом коде условия для возникновения конкретного исключения при определённых условиях

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите исключать эти ошибки, то можно воспользоваться:

```
except Exception:
    #code
```

except Exception - исключит **все** ошибки которые могут вылететь